# Creating a View from Multiple Tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, create-view

I am trying to create a view from the following tables that gives classId, semester, professor's name that taught it, and the number of sections offered that semester. I tried to create the view with the SQL Query:

```
CREATE SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW ClassesView AS SELECT Qualified.ClassId, Teaches.Semester, CONCAT(Professor.FName, Professor.LName) AS Name, Teaches.Section FROM Teaches, Professor, Qualified WHERE Qualified.EmpId = Professor.EmpId, Qualified.ClassId = Teaches.Class;
```

But that didn't work. How would I go about creating the desired view from the following tables?

```
CREATE TABLE Class
(
    ClassId VARCHAR(6),
    Description VARCHAR(30),
    NumCredits Integer,
    Prereq VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(ClassId)
);

CREATE TABLE Section
(
    ClassId VARCHAR(6),
    SecNo CHAR(10),
    Semester CHAR(4),
    ClassRoom VARCHAR(6),
    TimeOffered VARCHAR(18),
    PRIMARY KEY(SecNo),
    FOREIGN KEY(ClassId) REFERENCES Class(ClassId)  
);

CREATE TABLE Professor
(
    EmpId INTEGER,
    FName VARCHAR(10),
    LName VARCHAR(10),
    Dept VARCHAR(2),
    QualClass VARCHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (EmpId)
);

CREATE TABLE Teaches
(
    Class VARCHAR(5),
    Section INTEGER,
    Semester CHAR(4),
    EmpId INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (EmpId) REFERENCES Professor(EmpId)
);

CREATE TABLE Qualified
(
    EmpId INTEGER,
    ClassId VARCHAR(5)
);
```

Thank you. Any help would be much appreciated as it will assist me in learning MySQL.

Comment: Don't use last century's implicit (comma-) join syntax. Come join the 21st century with proper, explicit, JOIN syntax!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error (Replace the comma with an AND)

```
CREATE SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW ClassesView AS 
SELECT Qualified.ClassId, Teaches.Semester, CONCAT(Professor.FName, Professor.LName) AS Name, Teaches.Section 
FROM Teaches, Professor, Qualified 
WHERE Qualified.EmpId = Professor.EmpId AND Qualified.ClassId = Teaches.Class;
```